# Angular custom form validation - Disable submit button

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I am checking if the username exists in firebase database and I am able to alert the user with a message if its already taken.

how do I disable submit button ?

```
<form ng-submit="validateForm()" style="margin-left:100px; margin-top:50px;">

<div class="form-group">

  <label>User Name</label>
  <input ng-model="user.userName" required type="text" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="userName">

  <ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in userObject">  
    <span ng-if="user.userName ==  key" class="text-danger">User name already exists!</span>
  </ul>

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd">Save</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Set a variable in the scope with false by default and set it to ngDisabled on submit button, use ngChanged to find it on firebase database and the result of the search into the previous variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to this.

in your controller

```
 if(user.userName ==  key)
 {
   $scope.chkuser= true;
 }
 else
 {
   $scope.chkuser= false;
 }
```

and set this variable it to ngDisabled on submit button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd"   ngDisabled="chkuser">Save</button>
```